# Syntax error when running a MySQL CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id     INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_name   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
user_pass   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_date   DATETIME NOT NULL,
user_level  INT(8) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX user_name_unique (user_name),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) TYPE=INNODB;
```

When running this query on the SQL server, I am getting the following error:

```
1064- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=INNODB' at line 10
```

Any help on why this is coming up?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of

```
TYPE=INNODB
```

set

```
Engine=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `ENGINE=InnoDB;`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `user_level` int(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user_name_unique` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The manual for [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) doesn't include TYPE; it seems to use:

```
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

And that is the default engine, so you don't really need to specify it.