# How do I fix: "...error in your SQL syntax; check the manual for the right syntax"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax-error

I am installing a program called Infinite Responder. I used to use it in the past and it worked fine. Anyway now I get this error when trying to install it

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server >version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 2"

How do I fix this and get it running? I don't know how to check my manual no would I know what to edit or change.

Comment: What is your full query

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620439/syntax-error-when-running-a-mysql-create-table-statement)

Comment: I have no idea what the full query is or how to find it. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe MySql no longer supports "TYPE=InnoDB". This syntax has been changed to "ENGINE=InnoDB" instead. If you can change this in your table create script that might fix the issue.

For Infinite Responder, you will need to open defs.sql and change all occurrences of TYPE=InnoDB to ENGINE=InnoDB.  After doing that, try and install it again.

Comment: That sounds great, thank you for the tip, however I don't know which file to look in for it. The page I run to get the error is just the default index which doesn't have 21 lines. I don't speak PHP but the index seems to include config.php and redirects to admin.php, but the word "TYPE" is not in either of those file. Is there a way to find out which file the bad code is in? Thanks

Comment: Updated answer to include instructions on where the sql is for Infinite Responder.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. As for my example, if it may help others, I was exporting from a mariadb(phpmyadmin) to mysql(phpmyadmin). **Step 1:** Export using the "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with" selected as "MYSQL40". **Step 2:** Run a find and replace with TYPE=InnoDB to ENGINE=InnoDB in your exported sql script. **Step 3:** When importing to mysql, make sure to choose MYSQL40 as the "SQL compatibility mode".