# Backwards compatible mysql dump

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to port a database from mysql 5.7 to mysql 5.5. 
At first, I used the following command

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldbs.sql
```

When I try to import the DB in mysql 5.5 I keep getting errors like

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 572: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'STATS_PERSISTENT=0' at line 9

where it complains about `STATS_PERSISTENT=0` statement.

Then I tried

```
mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=mysql40 --all-databases > alldbs.sql
```

but this just gives me

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 26: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB' at line 22

where it complains about `TYPE=InnoDB` statement, which should be `ENGINGE=InnoDB`. Even with the `--compatible` option it still keeps the `STATS_PERSISTENT` statement.

Is there a way to port a mysql 5.7 database to mysql 5.5?

**UPDATE**

To be clear on my question, I am looking for *relialble*, i.e. no-hack way, to port the database. I already tried to replace `TYPE` with `ENGINE`, remove `STATS_PERSISTENT` etc. Something else always came up. I am not willing to jump through those hoops everytime I port the database. I am looking for a reliable way via `mysqldump` or a similiar tool to do the job.

If this is not possible then I will have to switch to an alternative DB.

Comment: Try replace that `TYPE` to `ENGINE` in your dump file, but before that make sure, you've created a backup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620439/syntax-error-when-running-a-mysql-create-table-statement

Comment: You will have to switch to an alternative DB. I wish you the best of luck with the alternative DB.

Comment: @Mjh I was hoping to avoid that. Anyway, can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: I can't. I'm using MySQL and I'm pretty ok with it. Even if I recommended something, it'd be opinionated and that's not what we do on SO. Also, if you have the option to completely swap out the database software, I see no reason why you can't have 5.7 on both machines. But hey, that's just silly me :)

Comment: @Mjh Recommending a software that is capable of backwards compatibility is not an opinionated recommendation, in my opinion :). But I do not want to argue about that. The reason why I can/will not install the same version on both machines is that each is running a different OS, both Linux and the repositories provide those versions. But the main reason I would rather switch is because I do not want to invest time (been learning MySQL for a week) in a buggy software. No backwards compatibility as described in the above scenario is a dealbreaker for me, personally.

Comment: @nautical there's a lot of .. wrong in your statement. I don't know where to start so I won't. Try Postgres. Good luck with your task!

Comment: @Mjh There is nothing wrong. I just can/do not want to go into all the details since this is getting off-topic and space is limited in the comments. I have adopted certain routines over the years which have prevented me from wasting too much time on a wrong path. The compatibility was just one issue. Some further research shows that data integrity is not guaranteed by default in MySQL. I would have probably wasted a few weeks before finding that out. So my "instincts" were right about MySQL. I am currently looking into Postgres. Thanks.

Comment: Data integrity **is** guaranteed in MySQL, it is a **relational** database. I don't know where you're getting all your info, it seems like it's from 15 years ago when what you wrote was true. I'm all for using the right tool for the job and for using something that fits me personally so I can be expressive - I believe it's like that for other people, which is why we have so many tools at our disposal. But listing wrong facts and justifying your decision using those is plainly wrong and you've come to wrong conclusions. I hope Postgres will do what you're after.

Comment: @Mjh Once again, there is nothing wrong with what I posted. A websearch yields several results that unanimously state that integrity issues may arise with MySQL. Just one example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emgJtr9tIME. Even if MySQL (5.5 in aforementioned case) can be configured to ensure data integrity, it does not do so by default. That is, by default, an issue and a fact. I was under the impression that you are a skilled MySQL user and aware of this shortcoming and know how to work around it. Hence, I did not link to any evidence. Continue in next comment ...

Comment: @Mjh ... I hope we can both agree that a feature that does not work as intended is, in fact, a bug. You are actually disagreeing with my decision process but I have not posted false facts. You may disagree that buggy backwards compatibilty is not a good reason to dump a software. That is your opinion - nothing wrong with it. But, in my opinion, it is a major issue. An infrastructure may very well evolve over time. It may leverage features of a new version of a deployed software. Having to implement system-wide changes due to this may introduce instabilities and is therefore not advisable.

Comment: @nautical - I never disagree with opinions, but your research isn't really accurate. You think that database dumping relates to backwards compatibility - it doesn't, and there are other tools that are in use to export / sync databases which are not database dumps. The db can dump only the data using DDL it knows. Maintaining DDL which dates 15-20 years ago isn't a feature you'd want because mixing old and new language / features can only yield bugs.

Comment: When it comes to integrity, you will notice that most of these "researchers" are in reality fanboys that do nothing serious in their programming life, or they perform their research very, very sloppily. MySQL is a bit special compared to other databases and that's because of its pluggable storage engine architecture. Some engines are acid compliant, some aren't. What I can agree with you is that you don't find MySQL as the tool for you - that's cool, Postgres is an alternative which apparently might fit you - which is great. I'll stop here, we'll just drag this on and the solution was found.

Comment: Too late to the party, but did you get find a way to do this @user4918296 ? I am looking for this myself.